# Is it possible to configure Domino to redirect to a different smarthost based on subject-line triggers?

Tags: email, smtp, ibm-domino

I'd like to configure Lotus Domino to redirect outbound mail to a different downstream SMTP relay if a certain keyword is present in the subject line.

Is this possible?  If so, can someone elaborate on the high-level steps involved to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For that level of routing you'd need to use something much more flexible and programmable like Haraka. You could forward everything to a Haraka server, and then the get_mx hook could decide where to route the mail based on Subject.